# How do I fetch user from pointer on Parse.com?

Tags: pointers, parse-platform, include

I need help using `fetch()` in CloudCode on Parse.com

RIght now everything I do throws an error that says " Cannot create a pointer to an unsaved ParseObject".

I am starting to think that CloudCode is broken because it doesn't make sense at all because I'm not creating anything new or creating pointers.

It's simple as

```
 query.find().then(function(lists){
   lists.forEach(elem, i){
      elem.get('owner').fetch({
        success: function(user){
           console.log(user);
        }
      })
   }
 });
```

Where 'owner' is a pointer to a user object and the query is on a class that contains a Pointer (owner) and an Array of objects. Essentially I want to get the email of the owner to compare to the Array of objects that also contain emails.
Trying to use `include` with the query also doesn't work.

Comment: `find()` returns a list of objects. Shouldn't you be doing something like `lists[i].get("owner").fetch()` ?

Comment: is colTyp of 'owner' a pointer to _User?   only use the ".get('owner')"  if that is the case.  get + fetch would be redundant

Comment: I fixed my code to show the iteration and also owner is a pointer to a _User